# Location of O2 sensor on 1990 Toyota pickup

Tags: toyota, o2-sensor

I'm trying to locate the O2 sensor on my 1990 RWD 22R 2.4 Toyota pickup truck.

I've looked all over underneath the car by the driver's side seat. There is no O2 sensor on top of the exhaust pipe, where it was said to exist. One person said that this model doesn't have one! Is that true? Or where should I look?

Answer (score 2):

Since this is an OBDI vehicle, there will be only one O2 sensor located where the exhaust ports all come together in the exhaust manifold.

Answer (score 0):

The first O2 sensor was introduced in 1976 on a Volvo 240.  Your 1990 Toyota Pick-up truck should have at least one o2 sensor.

Here is an image to give you a general idea of location.

[image]

Comment: Next time just copy (download) the image using the icon at the top of the answer box ... it'll drop right in using the image URL.

Answer (score 0):

there are two oxygen sensors on the toyota pu one attached to the exaust manifold the second just beyond the catylytic converter located on the tailpipe